# メインカメラとサブカメラの切り替えができず困っています。

Tags: c#, unity3d

お邪魔します。表題の通り、あるシーンでメインカメラとサブカメラを切り替え、ボタンによりまた戻ってくる動作をしたいのですが、切り替えはできても元に戻す動作ができません。
理由が全く分からず困っております。アドバイス、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

問題のコードです。

```
public void PushButtonBackArea()
{
    subCamera.SetActive (false);
    mainCamera.SetActive (true);
}
```

・カメラはpublic変数でどちらもアタッチ済み。
・当スクリプト内で、逆（サブカメラのSetActive(true);,メインカメラのSetActive(false);）は動作します。
・また、コンポーネントのenabledでも試しましたが同様の結果です。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問の意図はわかりますが、もう少し詳細があった方が確実な回答ができるので、スクリプトの全文を載せて欲しいです。
今の内容からわかる程度の回答をします。

メインカメラとサブカメラが同じシーン上にあって、どちらかが非アクティブの状態で、カメラの切り替えをしたいということでよろしいでしょうか？

まず、自分の方でも試してみました。以下のようなヒエラルキーになっています。
MainCameraとSubCameraにはCameraコンポーネント以外には特にアタッチしていません。
[image: ヒエラルキー]

以下のスクリプトを任意のオブジェクトにアタッチしてシーン上に出し実行したところ問題なく動作しました。

```
public class switcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainCam;
    public GameObject subCam;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        mainCam.SetActive(true);
        subCam.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G)) {
            mainCam.SetActive(!mainCam.activeSelf);
            subCam.SetActive(!subCam.activeSelf);
        }
    }
}
```

補足： Unity 2018.3.0f2における動作です。環境が違う場合はその旨を追記してください。